# How do I find licenses of all installed ruby gems?

Tags: ruby

For legal needs, I need to document all the installed gems and their licences on our instances. The `gem list` command lists all the gems. Is there a programmatic way to also list the licenses?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**From the Rails console:**

For some Gems, which have its license information included inside its spec, you can display them running this from the *rails console*:

```
Gem.loaded_specs.each do |name, spec|
  puts "#{name}: #{spec.license}"
end
```

or **From your linux bash terminal:**

```
for i in `gem list | cut -d" " -f1`; do echo "$i :" ; gem spec $i license; done
```

Comment: Thank you. But both of these didn't work either. The first command only listed one gem and it looks like the second is not meant for the need I have. Ref: https://github.com/pivotal/LicenseFinder/issues/297

Comment: Sorry Vivek, I meant the rails console :-). If you run it from IRB you will only see one gem. You can run this from your linux terminal to see the licenses: __for i in \`gem list | cut -d" " -f1\`; do  echo "$i :" ; gem spec $i license; done__

Answer (score 2):

You can often find licensing information either on [rubygems.org](https://rubygems.org) (derived from the gemspec data) or on the developer's source code repository.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you @Myst. I've just edited my Question to clarify that I actually meant a programmatic way to get this information.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit late, but I googled it and this gem comes up and even supports CSV so if you're doing this business people it'll be great because then you can just send the spreadsheet up stream in your org.

Source:
https://rubygems.org/gems/license-list/versions/1.0.1